# Can't choose content type anymore

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms

I installed the Webform module on my drupal 7 install and now, when I select to create new content, I don't get asked to choose the content type (basic page, article, webform) anymore. Where is the setting for this? I need to be able to choose which content type I want to create.

Thank you!
Ron

Comment: What do you see at node/add? What about node/add/page?

Comment: There's no setting for that; the 'node/add' page is defined by code in [`node_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_menu/7). If it's gone missing, a custom/contrib module is probably to blame. If it happened after installing Webform, disable Webform temporarily to see if that's the culprit. If so, you've probably found a bug and should report it to the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/webform?categories=bug)

Comment: @Chris, both return "Page not found"

Comment: try clearing caches - your menu cache probably just needs to get rebuilt.

Comment: @schnippy, I tried that as well, retried it now but hasn't helped... :(

Comment: @Chris, ?q=node/add/ redirects automatically to ?q=node/add/webform, however, ?q=node/add/page let's me create a basic page...is this how I have to do it? :o

Comment: @Clive, even with disabled Webform component drupal links to ?q=node/add/webform - very odd but it won't let me create an actual form (of course with disabled module) but Webform content type i still there even with disabled module... ? :o

Comment: Go to your navigation menu: /admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation and look for your add content menu items. Are they enabled or disabled? I've seen these get disabled during these updates before. If that doesn't work, there could be something in your update that is breaking and blocking the menu update so check your error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a hiccup in the node menu rebuild after installing a new module. If you run into this issue, its likely due to one of three problems, which you can address in the following order:

- Clear full cache, forcing the content menu to rebuild
- Go to the menu options under /admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation and look for your add content menu items and make sure they are disabled
- If these two fail, then there is probably an error in your build that is preventing the menu from rebuilding correctly - check in your error logs for any issue there and address.